# Get the Size of a Document Set

Tags: 2010, document-set

I have a document library full of document sets and I need to figure out the size of each document set including their contents.  However I do not have access to the server nor the ability to touch it with code.  Effectively I am a Site Owner and can only do what I can through the UI.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea.

1. Navigate to the Document Set library
2. Go to the Library tab in the Library Tools section at the top of the page.
3. Click "Open with Explorer"
4. Rightclick the Document Set you want to view the size of and click "Properties"
5. The size of the folder will show the size of the document set with all of it's contents.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Mike said if you want to see document file sizes too you can go to library settings and then click on "All Documents" right bottom of page, check box "File Size" and then click ok.

The default view  for a Document Library "All Documents" does not include the file  size column. You can either modify this view or can create  a new custom view and set that view as default view

Hope it helps.